# Is this a Infinite loop? program finishes prematurely

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I´ve programmed a random writing program. That uses the markov algorithm. So it selects a order of letters, say `[th]` then go finding what appears most frequent after that using some randomness etc. But if the program selects a letter that has no "siblings". for example say right at the end of the file this symbol is `[%]` and it do not appear anywhere else in the file. What happens then is that the program just says `"Finished running"` it don´t even execute the `cout`command that prints out the string `newText`.

Why is this?

The rest of the code does basically some manipulation of arrays (adding etc..), to much code to post here.

```
for (int i = 0; i < fullText.length(); i++)
{
    newText += getNext(currentWord, curWordPos, order);
}

cout << "Output: " << newText << endl;
```

Comment: I feel your pain.  Once I had a program and it called a function `myFunc(a,b,c)` and it had an exception access violation.  Any ideas on how I can fix it?

Comment: Me too! My program is supposed to print an ASCII christmas tree to the screen but it does it in the wrong colour. Any help??

Comment: If the program *finishes* prematurely then it cannot *by definition* be an infinite loop. Perhaps it just crashes inside the loop...

Comment: Ok, I get it so in C++ no error-messages for this kind of stuff! it just finnish running.

Comment: Snarky humor for the regulars aside *(I'm a fan of jokes, but I don't downvote questions...usually)* you really haven't given enough information.  Consider reading through the documentation of [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).  Don't let the downvote dogpile discourage you, it's just a kind of hazing...but the goal is to give some feedback about the question asking technique.  No one in their right mind actually cares about the points.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `cout << "\033[22;31m"`.  *(You're welcome!  Happy holidays!)*

Comment: @HostileFork: Great that fixed it, thanks! How do I mark your answer as the solution???

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No need to thank me citizen, justice is its own reward.

Answer (score 4):

> Is this an Infinite loop?

No, it's not.

Comment: I am sure in quantum theory there exists stuff like infinite loops crashing. And then just says "Finish running"

Comment: @TomLilletveit: In a quantum program, all infinite loops run together at the same time, backwards _and_ forwards, crashing at all points and at all times.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You cannot know unless you are using a debugger though. Until then, the program is still alive and infinitely recursing in the box.

Comment: @thatidiotguy: Well, it is and it isn't.

Comment: @thatidiotguy How would one debug a quantum computer's execution? Single-step, step-in, step-over, and step-out at the same time?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: don't forget to shake it all about